# Don't find my database resource

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a database in my project called mydb.sqlite and I used:

```
databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

to get the path and ir returns `databasePath --> null` I check in my "Copy Bundle Resources" and it appears here. I think that I miss something.

Comment: try this NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/mydb.sqlite"]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling 
`[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydb" ofType:@"sqlite"];`
 in a NSObject. That is why it could find the database. Now I called it in a ControlView

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase
{ 
    //Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
   BOOL success;

    //Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
//of the database and to copy it over if required
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
   success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self databasePath]];

   NSLog(@"databasePath = %@",databasePath);

   NSLog(@"Success = %d",success);

// If the database already exists then return without doing anything
   if(success) return;

// If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

// Get the path to the database in the application package
   NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

// Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
   [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databaseName error:nil];

}


-(NSString *)databasePath
{
   NSString *docsDir;
   NSArray *dirPaths;

   // Get the documents directory
   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

   docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

   // Build the path to the database file
   NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YouDatabaseName.sqlite"]];

   return databasePath;
}
```

Call this check and create function in the applicationDidFinishLaunching in the AppDelegate

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried it doesnt work :/

Comment: Have you created the check and create method , which check if the database is present in the Document direntory or not , if the database is not present in the document directory it copies that database file to the document directory .

Comment: I think that I have found the solution, the problem was that I was calling `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mydb" ofType:@"sqlite"];` in a NSObject. thanks for your help.